# Draw lines with touch

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and I have no experience handling core graphics.
I need to develop an application in ios swift to draw graphs. Here graph refers to graph theory. I need to draw the nodes by tapping on the screen and draw lines between two nodes when they are selected. So far I can only draw circles, but I need that when touching two points a line appears between the two. And I need that if I already draw a circle, when they tap again they can move. How can I draw the lines?

I will appreciate any support

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            // Set the Center of the Circle
            // 1
            let circleCenter = touch.location(in: view)

            // Set a random Circle Radius
            // 2
            let circleWidth = CGFloat(25.7) //+ (arc4random() % 50))
            let circleHeight = circleWidth

            // Create a new CircleView
            // 3
            let circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: circleCenter.x, y: circleCenter.y, width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight))
            view.addSubview(circleView)
        }
    }
}
```

Class CircleView.swift

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Get the Graphics Context
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

            // Set the circle outerline-width
            context.setLineWidth(5.0);

            // Set the circle outerline-colour
            UIColor.red.set()

            // Create Circle
            let center = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2)
            let radius = (frame.size.width - 10)/2
            context.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 2.0, clockwise: true)

            // Draw
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is pretty unclear. You say you want to be able to draw lines and circles, however you should detail what differenciate these two touches (in the user perspective). Is it a button? is it a double tap? etc... 
Try to reformulate what you are trying implement here, it will be easier for us to understand your needs

Comment: First I need to draw the circles or points using the Touch. And then if I select two points from which I draw then connect them with a line. In my case I already have the points but I need to connect them with lines. I hope I explained it well

Comment: What is unclear is the « select » part. One touch equals drawing a circle, so how do you select the circle? With a long pressure? If yes you can catch the long press event, collect the coordinates of the closest circle, then switch to a state where the next touch will collect the coordinates of a second circle. (With a boolean and 2 CGPoint variables). Immediatly after having the second circle coordinates you draw a line between the two CGPoints, switch out of the state and nillify the two vars.

Comment: (Btw the solution I suggested above implies not relying on a UIView to draw your circle, but drawing it directly on a global draw view for every components, retaining coordinates of your circles with an array for instance)

Comment: Thank you!! Maybe the way I think about it is not entirely correct.